# Looping copied list and deleting from original list deletes from copied list

Tags: python

The snippet of code that's messing up:

```
equ2 = ['+', '10', '+', '2', '-', '2', '+', '4']
flag4 = [ ]

for k in equ2[:]:
    if equ2[equ2.index(k)-1] == '+':
        del(equ2[equ2.index(k)])
        flag4.append('-' + k)
    elif equ2[equ2.index(k)-1] == '-':
        del(equ2[equ2.index(k)])
        flag4.append('+' + k)
print flag4
```

*Edit: I messed up the variables, sorry about that :x

*Edit2: Sorry again D: jedwards, that is the output I'm getting, I got the other output by deleting from the copied list

Output I'm getting:

```
['-10', '-2', '--', '-2', '-4']
```

Output I want:

```
['-10', '-2', '+'2, '-4']
```

I figured out that when it got to the '-', it checks the original list (now modified to + - 2 + 4), and sees that the item before the '-' is a '+', so it appends '--', then checks the original list again (now + 2 + 4) and sees the '+' before the 2, so it appends '-2' (fixes itself sorta after that). Is it checking the original list the whole time?

Comment: Can you post your exact code, at least the parts where `equ2` and `flag4` are set as well as where you print the output?  Running the code with `equ2 = "10 + 2 - 2 + 4"; flag4 = list()`  and printing `flag4` doesn't generate the output you say you're getting.

Comment: After your edit, output *I'm* getting: `['-10', '-2', '--', '-2', '-4']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really conviced this is the best way to do this, the following works

```
equ2 = ['+', '10', '+', '2', '-', '2', '+', '4']
flag4 = list()

chgsgn = dict([('+','-'), ('-','+')])

while len(equ2):
    sgn = equ2.pop(0)
    num = equ2.pop(0)

    flag4.append(chgsgn[sgn] + num)


print flag4
```

Which outputs

```
['-10', '-2', '+2', '-4']
```

***Edit:*** Alternatively, using list comprehensions and not modifying `equ2`:

```
chgsgn = dict([('+','-'), ('-','+')])
flag4 = [chgsgn[sgn]+num for (sgn,num) in zip(*[iter(equ2)]*2)]
print flag4
```

Which also outputs

```
['-10', '-2', '+2', '-4']
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot simpler (and more effective) than what I've been doing so far... Thank you :D

Comment: `pop(0)` causes the remaining items of the list to be copied/moved, so this is not very efficient

Comment: @gnibbler, agreed -- I threw up a list comprehension version that should be more efficient as it doesn't shift (or even modify) `equ2`.

Comment: @jedwards, bears a passing resemblance to the LC in my answer :)

Comment: @gnibbler, wow thats funny.  Your dictionary is cooler and you decreased the line count by 50%!

Answer (score 2):

The indices you are trying to modify are out of sync after the first element is deleted from the list.

There are better ways to loop pairwise, but it's not clear to me what the loop is supposed to do in the general case

eg.

```
>>> flag4 = [dict(['+-','-+'])[i] + j for i,j in zip(*[iter(equ2)]*2)]
>>> print flag4
['-10', '-2', '+2', '-4']
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix it? Maybe create a copy of the list, loop the copy and delete from the original?

Comment: @asqapro: Can you explain more clearly what the purpose is? If all you want to do is remove the +/- from the equ2 list, and collapse each pair of the list, than there are much easier ways to do it.

Comment: I want the loop to reverse every operator (+ becomes -, etc), and to append the reversed operator and the integer it was with to flag4

Comment: Do you care that the original elements are removed from equ2 or was that just a side effect?

Comment: Side effect, it doesn't matter if they're removed